# How is Ruby's sorting implemented?

Tags: c, ruby, sorting, memory-management

I am curious to know how `sort_by` and `sort_by!` are implemented. I looked at some of the implementation code, but wasn't able to parse through the immense number of macros (that in turn yielded more macros) to figure out what was actually happening.

Here are the results from my benchmarking:

```
sort_by -a[:bar]       8.830000   0.010000   8.840000 (  8.847953)
sort_by a[:bar]*-1     8.620000   0.010000   8.630000 (  8.628056)
sort_by(&:bar).reverse!  8.550000   0.000000   8.550000 (  8.558410)
```

vs:

```
sort_by! -a[:bar]      2.800000   0.000000   2.800000 (  2.800778)
sort_by! a[:bar]*-1    2.690000   0.000000   2.690000 (  2.692756)
sort_by!(&:bar).reverse!  2.470000   0.010000   2.480000 (  2.480710)
```

I'm curious to know why there's such a significant difference. One hypothesis I had is around memory allocation that `sort_by` has to do. But here's my benchmarking code, you can see that it's an array I'm sorting (i.e. allocation can happen once, array size is known).

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'benchmark'

foo = []
for i in 0..10000
  foo << {:bar => rand(10000)} 
end

Benchmark.bm(20) do |b|
  b.report("sort_by! -a[:bar]") { 1000.times { foo.sort_by!{ |a| -a[:bar] } } }
  b.report("sort_by! a[:bar]*-1") { 1000.times { foo.sort_by!{ |a| a[:bar]*-1 } } }
  b.report("sort_by!(&:bar).reverse!") { 1000.times { foo.sort_by!{ |a| a[:bar] }.reverse! } }
end
```

Comment: `sort_by` needs to create a whole new array, so should be slightly slower than `sort_by!`. Internally they should be fairly similar, but reading the Ruby source code would be the best way to test any theories.

Comment: @tadman, +1 for "reading the Ruby source code would be the best way to test any theories."

Comment: The whole point of this post was that I couldn't parse through the Ruby source code... I know that would be the easiest way of going about it, but I figured that I would leverage the collective knowledge here.'

Comment: Your benchmark is flawed. In the code you posted (using `sort_by!`), the `foo` is actually sorted once in the first iteration. After that, it is already sorted for the subsequent loops which means that the algorithm finishes significantly faster. In the case of `sort_by` however, the sorting would actually happen a thousand times which naturally takes longer on an unsorted array. When using a proper benchmark (by introducing `.dup` before the sort), `sort_by` is even slightly faster than `sort_by!` in my tests on Ruby 2.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your benchmarks don't reflect the outputs, plus they are in need of simplification. When you test keep it simple and test only what you want to know about:

```
require 'benchmark'

BAR = (1..10_000).to_a.shuffle

n = 1000
Benchmark.bmbm(8) do |b|
  b.report("sort_by")  { n.times { foo = BAR.dup; foo = foo.sort_by{ |a| a }; foo } }
  b.report("sort_by!") { n.times { foo = BAR.dup; foo.sort_by!{ |a| a };      foo } }
end
```

Resulting in:

```
Rehearsal --------------------------------------------
sort_by    6.350000   0.010000   6.360000 (  6.364429)
sort_by!   6.620000   0.000000   6.620000 (  6.615428)
---------------------------------- total: 12.980000sec

               user     system      total        real
sort_by    6.350000   0.000000   6.350000 (  6.353188)
sort_by!   6.840000   0.010000   6.850000 (  6.842521)
```

The environment probably hadn't stabilized in your tests, plus you were throwing in changes that confuse the tests.

It's important to duplicate everything, with only one thing different, to test just the thing you want to know about. `sort_by!` mutates the array. `sort_by` returns a new array so, to have the same result, you should assign the result to the array also.

---

This test bears repeating:

```
require 'benchmark'

BAR = (1..10_000).to_a.shuffle

n = 1000

Benchmark.bmbm(12) do |b|
  b.report("sort (no block)")  { n.times { foo = BAR.dup; foo = foo.sort;                   foo } }
  b.report("sort! (no block)") { n.times { foo = BAR.dup; foo.sort!;                        foo } }
  b.report("sort (block)")     { n.times { foo = BAR.dup; foo = foo.sort{ |a, b| a <=> b }; foo } }
  b.report("sort! (block)")    { n.times { foo = BAR.dup; foo.sort!{ |a, b| a <=> b };      foo } }
  b.report("sort_by")          { n.times { foo = BAR.dup; foo = foo.sort_by{ |a| a };       foo } }
  b.report("sort_by!")         { n.times { foo = BAR.dup; foo.sort_by!{ |a| a };            foo } }
end
```

Resulting in:

```
Rehearsal ----------------------------------------------------
sort (no block)    1.250000   0.010000   1.260000 (  1.253412)
sort! (no block)   1.240000   0.010000   1.250000 (  1.254230)
sort (block)      12.380000   0.010000  12.390000 ( 12.378503)
sort! (block)     12.390000   0.000000  12.390000 ( 12.399870)
sort_by            6.410000   0.010000   6.420000 (  6.408380)
sort_by!           6.720000   0.000000   6.720000 (  6.727324)
------------------------------------------ total: 40.430000sec

                       user     system      total        real
sort (no block)    1.240000   0.010000   1.250000 (  1.249624)
sort! (no block)   1.230000   0.020000   1.250000 (  1.241353)
sort (block)      12.320000   0.010000  12.330000 ( 12.341552)
sort! (block)     12.390000   0.010000  12.400000 ( 12.397626)
sort_by            6.410000   0.010000   6.420000 (  6.411413)
sort_by!           6.940000   0.000000   6.940000 (  6.943647)
```

There are two "take-aways" from this:

- `sort` outruns `sort_by` when comparing basic objects without a block so use the `sort` family without a block if you can.
- If you're sorting and using a block to reach into the objects to find what you're sorting, or if you are doing a calculation to determine the sort value, then use the `sort_by` family.

Comment: using the `foo = BAR` stuff is unneccessary or at least doesn't help. after the first loop of a `sort_by!` or `sort!` test, the BAR array fill also be sorted. Yu need to use something `BAR.dup.sort!` to actually have reproducable and comparable results.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I was concentrating on other parts of the demo. It's easily fixed so I'll adjust the examples.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing here: `sort_by!` is defined on Array and thus can be optimized for arrays, while `sort_by` is defined on Enumerable, so it has to be able to handle all kinds of enumerables.